# Local costmap not visible

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I used navigation stack wit move base on my lidar. It could generate path to the goal, and display global costmap, However, the local costmap is empty with zeros, while the lidar has data generated (non-zeros).
I searched around and people suggesting that the min. obstacle height and max. obstacle height of the laser scan is the problem, I tried it out, but it still doesn't work, could anyone kindly advise what I could change?

base_local_planner_params.yaml:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 1.0
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.4

  acc_lim_theta: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: false
```

costmap_common_params.yaml:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.305, -0.18], [-0.305, 0.18], [0.305, 0.18], [0.305, -0.18]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor #point_cloud_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: frame_name, data_type: LaserScan, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}

#point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: frame_name, data_type: PointCloud, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

global_costmap_params.yaml:

```
global_costmap:
    footprint: [[-0.305, -0.18], [-0.305, 0.18], [0.305, 0.18], [0.305, -0.18]]
    footprint_padding: 0.01
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_frequency: 5.0
    publish_frequency: 5.0

    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_footprint
    resolution: 0.05

    rolling_window: false
    track_unknown_space: true

    plugins: 
        - {name: static,    type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}            
        - {name: sensor,    type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
        - {name: inflation, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

    static:        
        map_topic: /map 
        subscribe_to_updates: true

    sensor:
        observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
        laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}

    inflation:
        inflation_radius: 2.5
        cost_scaling_factor: 6.0
```

local_costmap_params.yaml:

```
local_costmap:
    footprint: [[-0.305, -0.18], [-0.305, 0.18], [0.305, 0.18], [0.305, -0.18]]
    footprint_padding: 0.01
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_frequency: 10.0
    publish_frequency: 10.0

    global_frame: /odom
    robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
    resolution: 0.05
    static_map: false
    rolling_window: true
    width: 2.0
    height: 2.0
    resolution: 0.1

    plugins:            
        - {name: sensor,    type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
        - {name: inflation, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

    sensor:
        observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
        laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, max_obstacle_height: 2.0, min_obstacle_height: 0.0, inf_is_valid: true}

    inflation:
        inflation_radius: 2.5
        cost_scaling_factor: 8.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319646/local-costmap-not-visible/) by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2019-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-27**:\

> An `inflation_radius` of `2.5` is very high, the unit is **meter** you should have something equivalent to the size of your robot

Or the robot is just really big and clunky, and 2.5m is really needed to avoid it running into things .. ;)

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-27**:
That would be a really clunky robot indeed, and I wouldn't get one :)

**Comment by [IvyKK](https://answers.ros.org/users/37889/ivykk/) on 2019-03-28**:
Yes. Thanks!! that's the problem.. I reorganized the code and it works okay now!

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-03-28**:
Can you answer your own question specifying what exactly solved the issue ? Was it the code organization or just the inflation radius (or both) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are few things to say (not sure if they are causing the issue though but that would improve your code):

- You should reorganize your files to actually have the common params only in the `costmap_commons_param.yaml`. For example the footprint doesn't have to be in your 3 files.
- An `inflation_radius` of `2.5` is very high, the unit is **meter** you should have something equivalent to the size of your robot (in your case it should be around 0,35 if you allow the robot to be close to the obstacles).
- You have defined the resolution twice with different values in the `local_costmap` file.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1